# Animated series about three kids and powered animals in a jungle

Tags: story-identification, magical-creatures, animated-series

I don't really remember it, but I'll say what I vaguely do. I think I watched it on Netflix, but it was quite a while ago, so I'm not sure. And it would have to be in the 2010s that I watched it. I think the animation was 2D.

Basically, I think there were three kids and there was like this lab where there were three tubes that they stepped into and like their scientist/backup guys who provided intel in the lab would click a button or something and the tube would close and teleport them into what I think was like a massive jungle with ruins and like robots that tried to get them and all that. I also think there was like a giant tiger that had powers or was just really strong and could talk that they found.

If anybody knows what this series is, please tell me. I've been searching for it for way too long.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?

Comment: I'm honestly losing my mind like idek whether its something I made up as a kid anymore

Comment: Umm I think I watched it on Netflix but it was quite a while ago so I'm not sure and it would have to be in the 2010s that I watched it

Comment: Did the show use 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated) animation?

Comment: I think it was 2d

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[Invizimals](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4900224/)*** (2013)...?

From the [Invizimals Wiki](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Invizimals_(TV_Series)):

> What if I told you a scientist called Kenichi Nakamura had discovered invisible creatures living all around us? What if I told you he'd discovered a gate to travel from our world to theirs? And what if I told you we were embarking on a quest to unravel the mysteries of the Invizimals' world? Wanna join our team? Meet us after class. We are the Alliance of Invizimal Hunters, and we could really use your help.

A scientist named Kenichi Nakamura is studying mysterious creatures known as Invizimals. His laboratory contains a *Stargate*-like portal, through which he sends three kids -- [Hiro](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Hiro), [Lima](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Lima) and [Sam](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Sam) -- to another world to study Invizimals in their natural habitats. When the kids have completed a mission, they travel back to Kenichi's lab through the portal, and are returned to their homes in different countries on Earth via *Star Trek*-like transporters.

> [image: Image of Hiro, Lima and Sam being transported to Kenichi's lab.]

In the first episode, the kids are initially on an observation mission in an icy environment, but later in the episode, they're sent to a jungle with ancient ruins, where they encounter hostile robots and an Invizimal named [Tigershark](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Tigershark). Near the start of the second episode, Tigershark gives Hiro a crystal and tells him to use it if he's ever in peril.

Comment: Yes that is it tysm

Comment: @Isabelle - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.